# Can't route from Login View to Master-Detail (FlexibleColumnLayout) View

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I tried to add https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.f.tutorial.fiori2/sample/sap.f.tutorial.fiori2.13
to my project where I route from my login view to Start view and then to the master detail view.
it is important for me to have my rootView viewName set to my Login page, if I set it to view.App <- than it works, but thats not what I want.

manifest.json

```
"sap.ui5": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "RCenter.view.app",
            "type": "XML"
        },
----------------------------------SKIPPING TO ROUTING-------------------------------------------------------
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "RCenter.view",
                "bypassed": {
                },
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "Start",
                    "name": "Start",
                    "controlId": "idStart",
                    "target": "TargetStart"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "Login",
                    "name": "Login",
                    "target": "TargetLogin"
                },

            
                {
                    "pattern": "page2",
                    "name": "page2",
                    "target": "page2",
                    "layout": "EndColumnFullScreen"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": ":layout:",
                    "name": "master",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "detail"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "detail/{product}/{layout}",
                    "name": "detail",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "detail"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "detail/{product}/detailDetail/{supplier}/{layout}",
                    "name": "detailDetail",
                    "target": [
                        "App",
                        "master",
                        "detail",
                        "detailDetail"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "TargetStart": {
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "controlId": "idStart",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "controlAggregation": "pages",
                    "viewName": "Start"
                },
                "TargetLogin": {
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "controlId": "idStart",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "controlAggregation": "pages",
                    "viewName": "Login"
                },
                "master": {
                    "viewName": "Master",
                    "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
                    "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages"
                },
                "detail": {
                    "viewName": "Detail",
                    "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
                    "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
                },
                "detailDetail": {
                    "viewName": "DetailDetail",
                    "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
                    "controlAggregation": "endColumnPages"
                },
                "page2": {
                    "viewName": "AboutPage",
                    "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
                    "controlAggregation": "endColumnPages"
                }
            }
        }
```

App.View

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="RCenter.controller.App"
    displayBlock="true"
    height="100%"
    xmlns="sap.f"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <FlexibleColumnLayout
        id="flexibleColumnLayout"
        stateChange=".onStateChanged"
        backgroundDesign="Solid"
        layout="{/layout}"/>
</mvc:View>
```

I mostly get Control with ID idStart could not be found - Target: TargetStart
Login.view & Start.view App-ID:

```
    <App 
        id="idStart">
```

idStart is the id of  in Login.view and Start.view (After Login you will get redirected to Start and there you will get redirected to the master detail view if you click on a certain button.

How can I get the Master-Detail Page of the example Link shown above working in my Project but without setting it as rootView-viewName??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The router is picking the control; based in rootView and the given ID. In your case the control with the ID "app".

Routing simply changes the view under the aggregation pages of the "app" control.
Hence, setting it to a login view makes no sense.

As you use a flexible column layout, the router should target the layout and not app.